# ng-pattern regex to match multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I'm using ng-pattern to validate a field for the following conditions. Thus far I'm only able to validate the last two conditions using the following regex. When I add only numbers, I'd like to validate the length as well.

How can I validate all four conditions inside ng-patter? Do I need to surround then with brackets separately?

```
data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9-\s()+]+$/"

11111111
111111111
11-111-111
111-111-111
```

I'd like to validate multiple conditions

Comment: Could you descrive the paaterns you want to match with words? This might also help you to create regex yourself. Maybe `^\d{2,3}(\-?)\d{3}\1\d{3}$` is already what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `^[1-9][0-9]{6}*$` is it is an **invalid regex** because of `{6}*` and `^([^0][0-9]){6}$` is that it is allowing any character that is not `0` followed by **six** digits.

Use

`^[1-9][0-9]{5}$`

**Explanation:**

1. `^`: Starts with anchor
2. `[1-9]`: Matches exactly one digit from 1 to 9
3. `[0-9]{5}`: Matches exactly five digits in the inclusive range `0-9`
4. `$`: Ends with anchor

[image: Regex Visualization]

**Regex101 Playground**

**HTML5 Demo:**

Show code snippet

`input:invalid {
  color: red;
}`
`<input type="text" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{5}" />`
 Run code snippetHide results

Answer (score 0):

try this. it will only allow 10 digits.

```
/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/
```

i'm not sure this would work but i tried.

```
/^[1-9]{1}[0-9-\s()+]{10}$/gm
```

Explainlation

1) ^ Beginning. Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled.

2) [ Character set. Match any character in the set.
1-9 Range. Matches a character in the range "1" to "9" (char code 49 to 57).
]

3) {1} Quantifier. Match 1 of the preceding token.

4) [ Character set. Match any character in the set.

5) 0-9 Range. Matches a character in the range "0" to "9" (char code 48 to 57).

6) - Character. Matches a "-" character (char code 45).

7) \s Whitespace. Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).

8) ( Character. Matches a "(" character (char code 40).

9) ) Character. Matches a ")" character (char code 41).

10) + Character. Matches a "+" character (char code 43).
]

11) {10} Quantifier. Match 10 of the preceding token.

12) $ End. Matches the end of the string, or the end of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled.

13) g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

14) m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: Hi There, thanks for the answer. I need: with hypens 10 or 11 and without hypens 8 or 9. Does this need to be seperated at all?

Comment: @Jimi Are you using this regex for validating phone numbers? if yes i have a better solution

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the help. I managed to find a cool generator online that gave me this: \b\d{2,3}[-]?\d{3}[-]?\d{3}\b it seems to do what I'm looking for.